# Inno Setup - Create User Input Query Page with input length and format limit and use the input

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

So, as the title says, I want to create a User Input Query Page (that's easy), but then I want the field to reject space character(s) and limit the input to no more than 15 characters (a bit more difficult for me). But then I need to write the input to a file, which I'm also not sure how to do.

Here's what my code looks like now:

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;

Procedure InitializeWizard();
Begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectTasks, 'Choose a Profile Name', 'This name will be used as your Profile Name', 'Please specify a name to be used as your Profile Name (make sure it''s unique), then click Next.');
  Page.Add('Name:', False);
  Page.Values[0] := 'YourName';
End;

function GetUserInput(param: String): String;
Begin
  result := Page.Values[0];
End;
```

As you can see, this code has no limitations for characters. That's the first thing I need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length limit is easy, use `TPasswordEdit.MaxLength` property.

To prevent the user from typing a space, filter it in `TEdit.OnKeyPress` event.

But you need to check explicitly for spaces in the end anyway, because the spaces can also be pasted from clipboard for example. For a final check, use `TWizardPage.OnNextButtonClick` event.

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;

{ Prevent user from typing spaces ... }
procedure EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = ' ' then Key := #0;
end;

{ ... but check anyway if some spaces were sneaked in }
{ (e.g. by pasting from a clipboard) }
function ValidateInput(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  
  if Pos(' ', Page.Values[0]) > 0 then
  begin
    MsgBox('Profile Name cannot contain spaces.', mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(...);
  Page.OnNextButtonClick := @ValidateInput;
  Page.Add('Name:', False);
  Page.Edits[0].MaxLength := 15;
  Page.Edits[0].OnKeyPress := @EditKeyPress;
  Page.Values[0] := 'YourName';
  ...
end;
```

---

Another possibility is to implement the `OnChange`.
See [Inno Setup Disable Next button when input is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43738431/850848).

---

As you already know, to use the entered value, access it via `Page.Values[0]`.