# Disallow empty and spaces-only input on Inno Setup custom page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there a way to disallow user input if it contains spaces only?
I already tried this solution:
[Inno Setup - Create User Input Query Page with input length and format limit and use the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684128/inno-setup-create-user-input-query-page-with-input-length-and-format-limit-and)

But, I don't want that solution because it disable -space- completely.
E.g. if input in text field is "my name" it will return error because -space- is not allowed.

Comment: What does it mean *"ignore"*? What **exact** behavior do you want?

Comment: I want if user enter only "spaces" in text field and click "next", an error message display and remain in same page till he enter valid characters. but when i tried the code above, it display an error "that text field can not contain any spaces", but as i want there is no problem if field contains "spaces", i just want to prevent user to enter only "spaces" eg. Name: [          ], but if the enter Name as: [MY NAME] it contains spaces and it's valid input. @MartinPrikryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same code as in:
[Inno Setup - Create User Input Query Page with input length and format limit and use the input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34684128/850848)

Just use this implementation of `ValidateInput`:

```pascal
function ValidateInput(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if Trim(Page.Values[0]) = '' then
  begin
    MsgBox('Input cannot be empty.', mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

The [`Trim` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_trim) is the key.

Comment: should i repeat the code above in every page.Values[] in all pages ? @Martin Prikryl

Comment: It's rather vague question. But, in general, **yes**.